# Retrieve sub-documents that match with maximum value in the array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following data structure in mongodb

```
[
    {
        "id" : "unique id 1",
        "timeStamp" : "timeStamp",
        "topicInfo" : [
            { 
                topic : "topic1", 
                offset : "offset number",
                time: 1464875267637
            },
            { 
                topic : "topic2", 
                offset : "offset number",
                time: 1464875269709
            },
            { 
                topic : "topic3", 
                offset : "offset number",
                time : 1464875270849
            }
       ]
   },
   {
       "id" : "unique id 2",
       "timeStamp" : "timeStamp",
       "topicInfo" : [
           { 
               topic : "15", 
               offset : "offset number",
               time : 1464875271884
           },
           { 
               topic : "topic2", 
               offset : "offset number",
               time : 1464875273887
           },
           { 
               topic : "topic3", 
               offset : "offset number",
               time : 1464875272848
           }
       ]
   }
 ]
```

Now I want to find all the entry That has topic called "topic2" and the value of time is maximum compare to other object's in the "topicInfo" array. I also want to sort them by "timeStamp". From the example code the query should return the second object. I am not able to write the query any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why is "time" string in your document?

Comment: Sorry I am editing it. It is actually time in millisecond.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The optimal best way to do this is in MongoDB 3.2 or newer. We need to [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) our documents and use the [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) operator to return a subset of the "topicInfo" array that matches our condition. And as of MongoDB3.2 , we can use the [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) in the `$project` stage in the `cond`ition expression and perform a logical operation on the returned value.

The final stage in the pipeline is the [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) stage where you filter out those documents with empty "topicInfo" using the [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) element query operator and the [*dot notation*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) to access the first element in the array. This also reduces both the amount of data sent over the wire and the time and memory used to decode documents on the client-side.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": { 
        "topicInfo": { 
            "$filter": { 
                "input": "$topicInfo", 
                "as": "t", 
                "cond": { 
                    "$and": [ 
                        { "$eq": [ "$$t.topic", "topic2"] }, 
                        { "$eq": [ "$$t.time", { "$max": "$topicInfo.time" } ] }
                    ] 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    }},
    { "$match": { "topicInfo.0": { "$exists": true } } }
])
```

Comment: It is returning all the but expected object has topicInfo array non empty where non expected object has it empty. I can figure out from there by doing application layer operation. However is this the optimal solution or is there a way to filter only the expected entry.

Comment: @MustafaMamun Yes this is the optimal way. I've updated my answer which now select only those documents with non empty array.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with aggregation framework like this:

```
db.test.aggregate(
    { $unwind: '$topicInfo' }, 
    { $match: { 'topicInfo.topic': 'topic2' } }, 
    { $group: { 
        _id: '$id', 
        timestamp: { $first: '$timestamp' }, 
        time: { $max: '$topicInfo.time' } } 
     }, 
     { $sort: { timestamp: 1 } }).pretty()
```