# Retrieve only documents with the highest value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I want to write a query that finds the documents with the highest value. There are multiple documents with the same value, and I want all of them.

I know I can use sort to sort from high to low. But I don't know how many documents there are. So that won't work.

```
{
     total: 1,
     id: 1
},
{
    total: 1,
    id: 2
},
{
    total: 2,
    id: 3
},
{
    total: 2,
    id: 4
},
{
    total: 3,
    id: 5
},
{
    total: 3,
    id: 6
}
```

In this example I want it to return all documents that have total `3`.
How can I query for all documents that have the highest value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve sub-documents that match with maximum value in the array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37594665/retrieve-sub-documents-that-match-with-maximum-value-in-the-array)

Comment: Even better the answer is here. [How can I get the lowest values in a MongoDB collection?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37504155/3100115)

Answer (score -1):

This will work for you:

```
db.yourcollectionname.aggregate([
    {
        $group:{
            _id: null,
            high_val: {$max:"$total"}
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup:{
           from: "yourcollectionname",
           localField: "high_val",
           foreignField: "total",
           as: "elements"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$elements"
    },
    {
        $project:{
            _id:false,
            id: "$elements.id",
            total: "$elements.total"
        }
    }
]);
```

Here **$lookup** is used to take the max value retrieved from the initial **$group**, and apply it back to the same table to retrieve the matching records.

I'm certain there is a better way to do this, but I couldn't resist, as I've just started using **$lookup**, so just exploring what it can do.

Answer (score -2):

you can do something like this

```
var a = db.tot.find().sort({"total":-1});
 var maxTotal = 0; 
 while (a.hasNext()) {

    var doc1 = a.next();

        if (doc1.total>=maxTotal) {
            maxTotal = doc1.total;
        }else {
            break;
        }
    db.doc2.insert(doc1);

 }
```

now you have all the documents with the highest value in collection doc2

Comment: why the negative rating ? did u even run the code ? I tried in my local and it works..

Comment: Hey, I didn't downvote you. Thank you for your answer!